# When multiple windows are captured simultaniously can OBS capture only cursor in currently active window?

Tags: linux, screen-casting, obs

I am making a small video for some of my colleagues where I show them how CI/CD with GitLab and Kubernetes works (software development stuff). For that purpose I would like too keep 4 windows visible at all time.

I am running OBS on Linux so I use xcompose for the Window Capture entities (WC). Respectively I added 4 separate WCs each with "Capture cursor" enabled.

Once I started recording the video I immediately realized that this was not the best way to set things up. In my head I imagined that the capturing of the cursor would only appear in the currently active window. Instead I have 4 WCs with each displaying my cursor and its motion across the screen. Needless to say this looks highly unprofessional not to mention distracting and disables me from e.g. pointing things out separately based on the WC I am currently viewing on my computer.

I cannot put all windows on my screen, since my screen is not really that big (just in case someone suggests that :D).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep recording all windows at same time(e.g. in same Scene) and they overlap this won't work(to my knowledge). Should be working if they don't, as it is for me in `OBS Studio - 30.0.2-1`.

Alternatively, you can use Tools -> Automatic Scene Switcher

Put each window in separate workspace if you wish.

1. Create separate scene for each Window Capture entity(WC)
2. In Automatic Scene Switcher create rules (select `Scene` you want to switch to when `Window name` gets focus)
3. Start/Activate Automatic Scene Switcher
   [image]